# don't return the result response after running pipeline (result is fail)

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

1) When the pipeline running the result has been successful and is done, I catch the response (DONE). and it print "Pipiline running result = DONE" on the console.

2) When the pipeline running the result has failed, I don't catch the response (FAILED), it just finishes. It does not print "Pipiline running result = FAILED". I can't go next step. I have tried using the `try/catch`, but it din't catch the 'PipelineExecutionException'.

```
    pipeline
        .apply(TextIO.Read.from(Path).named("TextIO.Read(" + Path + ")"))
        .apply(new MyTransforms());

    try{
        PipelineResult result = pipeline.run();

        LOG.info("  Pipiline running result = " + result.getState().toString());

        if (result.getState() != PipelineResult.State.DONE) {
            // i will send e-mail
        }
    }
    catch(PipelineExecutionException e){
        LOG.error(e.getMessage());
    }
```

The failed cause is "path(gcs) is empty".
I want to get the fail result response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, make sure you are using the BlockingDataflowPipelineRunner.  Otherwise, your code will terminate after the job as submitted.

With the BlockingDataflowPipelineRunner, you should catch DataflowJobExecutionException to handle unexpected failures, DataflowJobCancelledException to handle cancellations, or the superclass DataflowJobException to handle all possible non-successful terminations.

The PipelineResult will only be returned if the job is successful.  If you want to query properties of the job such as state or aggregators in the case of a failure, you can access the DataflowPipelineJob object from the exception that you caught with DataflowJobException#getJob().

Comment: i used the DataflowJobException as your comment.So I was able to handle cancel excption. thanks a lot.