# Can you run code after waitUntilFinish() is called in a Dataflow template?

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have a batch Apache Beam job that takes a file from GCS as input. My goal is to move the file to one of two GCS buckets depending on the pipeline's state after execution. If the pipeline executed successfully, move the file to bucket A, otherwise, if the pipeline had any kind of unhandled exceptions during execution, move the file to bucket B.

I'm using Apache Beam version 2.24.0 for Java, and I need to create a Dataflow template in order to run it multiple times with different input files.

Currently my approach is to run the pipeline with pipeline.run().waitUntilFinish(), wrapping the call with a try-catch and using the resulting PipelineResult.State object (null when there was an exception) to decide to which bucket to move the file.
Using the DirectRunner it works fine, but when creating a Dataflow template and executing it with DataflowRunner, it completely ignores any code outside of the pipeline execution graph.

Is there any way to execute code defined outside of the Dataflow template's execution graph?
I would like to achieve this directly in the same Java code, without the need to execute another program after the job finishes (e.g. Cloud Function).

Comment: Do you use custom template?

Comment: @Ines Yes, I'm creating my own custom template

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any way to execute code defined outside of the Dataflow template's execution graph?

Unfortunately no way to do it at the moment. You can execute some code outside of the graph, but it will run at the time when you create (stage) the template, not when you run a job from this template.

Basically, a "template" is a simply the serialized graph. When you the Beam program with DataflowRunner and with `--templateLocation` param, the `pipeline.run()` only serializes the graph to a file (for later use) instead of actually running a new job. That's why `waitUntilFinish()` doesn't work: when this code runs, there is no Dataflow job to wait for.

One possible solution is to use [`Wait.on`](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.38.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/Wait.html) to execute some additional logic when the pipeline is done processing main data. But the code still needs to be "inside" the graph and will run within a single Dataflow job.

Comment: What about flex templates?

Comment: The same is true for both Classic and Flex templates. Flex template code is executed at a later stage, but it still needs to produce a single serialized graph at some point. And it's still 1 template run = 1 Dataflow job. No way to create 2+ pipelines (2+ Dataflow jobs) from a single template invocation, with current architecture.

Comment: Wait.on() is also not working for the step after BiQueryIO.write()

Answer (score 0):

The reason for that could be that java Exception is thrown on the Dataflow worker and cannot be caught on host that submits the jobs.

If you want to to move the file to one of GCS buckets depending on the pipeline's state after execution, I would recommend to use the Dataflow API to query the final state of the job:

```
PipelineResult res = p.run();
  String jobId = ((DataflowPipelineJob) res).getJobId();
  DataflowClient client = DataflowClient.create(options);
  /* use client to poll final state */
```

Then, you can specify moving the files to the `bucket A` only when the job is successful and to the `bucket B` when the job failed.

Additionally, I want to share with you some useful links: exanple with [waitUntilFinish](https://github.com/googleapis/java-bigtable-hbase/blob/master/bigtable-dataflow-parent/bigtable-beam-import/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/bigtable/beam/sequencefiles/Utils.java#L74), [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32343951/dont-return-the-result-response-after-running-pipeline-result-is-fail/32363359#32363359).

Comment: The problem with the Dataflow API approach is that it seems like any code outside of the pipeline is ignored when using a Dataflow template. The exception handling and everything else works just fine when executed with the DirectRunner, but not when executed from a template with the DataflowRunner.

Comment: It is possible to run the code after waitToFinish(), check following [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41774664/delete-a-bigquery-table-after-all-the-steps-in-dataflow-job-have-completed)

Comment: Again, that doesn't work when using a Dataflow template.