# wait_until_finished() returns UNKNOWN does not wait for pipeline to complete

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

We have a Dataflow pipeline which begins with extracting data from BigQuery and the data are then written to CSV in a Google Bucket using `apache_beam.io`'s `WriteToText` function. Because the files are sharded we need to run a piece of code to merge the files together using `storage_client.compose()`. However, since we don't know *when* `WriteToText` completes its data export we're using [result.wait_until_finished()](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.19.0/apache_beam.runners.runner.html#apache_beam.runners.runner.PipelineResult.wait_until_finish) to wait for the export to complete and then continue with merging code.

On my local machine the flow of code runs as expected: The query gets called, then followed by file exports and then `result.wait_until_finished()` returns DONE and `storage_client.compose()` gets called.

The code runs in a flexible image. When running in Google Dataflow (ie. `--runner=DataflowRunner`) then `result.wait_until_finished()` returns UNKNOWN and it goes immediately to `storage_client.compose()` without the previous jobs ever having completed. The `compose()` method raises an exception since no files exist in the bucket.

1. Why does `wait_until_finished()` return UNKNOWN and what does it actually mean?
2. Why does `wait_until_finished()` not wait for the previous steps to complete?
3. If we can't use `wait_until_finished()` then how can we still merge the files in Dataflow?

Snippet of the code

```
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions
import argparse
from apache_beam.io import WriteToText
from google.cloud import storage

if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.INFO)
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("--extraction_query", help="A Big Query script to extract data")
    #other arguments removed

    known_args, beam_args = parser.parse_known_args()

    beam_args.append('--setup_file')
    beam_args.append('./setup.py')

    # Pipeline
        
    beam_options = PipelineOptions(beam_args, save_main_session=True)

    p = beam.Pipeline(options=beam_options)

    data_pipeline = (p
            | 'Execute extraction query' >> beam.io.Read(beam.io.BigQuerySource(query=known_args.extraction_query, use_standard_sql=True))
            )
    
    if (known_args.bigquery_export_bucket is not None):
        #variable preparations removed...

        (data_pipeline
        | 'Convert BigQuery data set to CSV' >> beam.Map(csv.convertDictToCSV, column_names)
        | 'Write data set to CSV' >> WriteToText(data_set_output, num_shards=31))

        (p
        | 'Create data set headers list' >> beam.Create([column_names])
        | 'Convert data set headers to CSV' >> beam.Map(csv.generateCSVHeader)
        | 'Write data set headers' >> WriteToText(data_set_headers_output))

    result = p.run()

    job_status = result.wait_until_finish(duration=7200000)
    logging.info(f'The pipeline completed with status {job_status}.')
    
    if (job_status == 'DONE' or job_status == 'UNKNOWN'):
        storage_client = storage.Client()
        export_bucket = storage_client.get_bucket({bucketId})
        export_blobs = list(storage_client.list_blobs(known_args.bigquery_export_bucket, prefix=known_args.bigquery_export_bucket_folder))
        
        blobs_to_compose = []
        for export_blob in export_blobs:
            blobs_to_compose.append(export_blob)
```

My question might resemble this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64046071/can-you-run-code-after-waituntilfinish-is-called-in-a-dataflow-template) although the question doesn't seem to have been answered.

Comment: I'm asking around about this. Just to be clear: your question is a bit different I think. That other question involves Dataflow flex templates, which have additional restrictions. What I am trying to figure out is why UNKNOWN is being treated as a terminal state.

Comment: Hi @KennKnowles, the script above is indeed executed in a flex template environment. I can update my original post with the Dockerfile if desired? Basically, we're using `gcr.io/dataflow-templates-base/python3-template-launcher-base:20220418_RC00` and runs `pip install -U apache-beam==2.39.0`. Can you expand a bit more on "the additional restrictions" on Dataflow flex templates?

Comment: The best answer is given on the question you linked to now: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72579118/949327

Comment: Actually that answer is primarily focusing on "classic" templates. For a flex template, though, the VM that is used to launch the job is not kept around while the job runs. So you cannot use wait_to_finish in that code. We generally suggest using Cloud Composer (aka Apache Airflow) to orchestrate jobs like you want to do.

Comment: Hi again, thanks for asking on the other thread, I re-implemented the code in our backend that calls Dataflow instead. I've accepted your Answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are actually a few variants of "unknown" job states:

- The SDK cannot get a job state from the Dataflow service.
- The Dataflow service reports that the job is in the `UNKNOWN` state.
- The Dataflow service reports a job state that the SDK does not understand. This can happen if new states are introduced in the service but you are using an older SDK. For example when the "drain" feature was introduced, it added a new `DRAINING` state that older SDKs do not know how to interpret.

In all cases, `UNKNOWN` should not be considered a terminal state, so `wait_until_finish` should keep waiting, unless the service separately indicates that the job is complete. I've confirmed this [in the code](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/a079e97bed6a7c677f23f91e3b67fc07e194aeb5/sdks/python/apache_beam/runners/runner.py#L363) which has been that way for a number of years, so if there is a problem it lies elsewhere.

The full documentation for job states is at https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/reference/rest/v1b3/projects.jobs#jobstate

Answer (score 1):

wait_until_finish() [isn't supported by flex templates](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/using-flex-templates#limitations) in google cloud dataflow.